# Pantheon crashes while dragging and dropping

Tags: release-juno, pantheon, crash

Sometimes the DE crashes while I move a file in a different directory. If I switch shell typing Ctrl+Alt+F2, to reboot, the prompt asks me to input the password but it does not recognize mine.

Now, since Elementary OS does not allow to set a Super User, How can I do in case everything freezes?

Comment: Please help me understand what do you mean by, "Elementary OS does not allow to set a Super User".

Comment: Hi, I mean that installing eOS you only set a user password. Sure you can elevate yourself to SU, task by task, with the terminal emulator, but this doesn't help (not for me) outside shell 7.